# Get output numbers to line up in columns?

Tags: python

I'm making just a little program to display primes. The code (below) produces the correct answer, but I'm having trouble with getting the output to look "nice".

```
import math
N = int(input('List primes up to: '))
maxDigits = math.ceil(math.log10(N)) #equal spacing, even with lesser digit stuff
for i in range(3,N,2):
    for d in range(2,int(math.sqrt(i))):
        if i%d==0:
            break
    else :
        print(str(i),end=' '*(maxDigits-len(str(i))))
```

The idea was to have as many columns as possible fit onto the output screen, based on the maximum number of digits the prime could have. But right now when I run the program it displays all the numbers in a long line, without any newlines. This results with the output looking like this:

[IT'S SO UGLY! IT BURNS MY EYES! http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/5522/2eyd.png](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/5522/2eyd.png)

Which...isn't exactly what I was going for. If it weren't for the fact that the numbers wrap over the lines, and just knew to go to the next line if there isn't enough space, everything would work fine. So how can I get rid of this annoying wrapping in my program? The more elegant (i.e. please don't tell me I have to count the terminal width and divide it by maxDigits) the better...:D

Comment: Count the terminal width and divide it by maxDigits.

Comment: Also, don't test this using the python command line. Save it to a file and run it with `python somefile.py`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams SAID NOT TO TELL ME TO DO THAT!!! No seriously, that's the best way of doing things? And how do I count the terminal width nonmanually?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid It does the same thing when I use the windows terminal (http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/913/uxgh.png)...

Comment: Please remember that you came here for help from volunteers who have absolutely no obligation towards you. Shouting is not a very good way to continue to get that help.

Comment: @MonadNewb Patronizing new users isn't exactly the best way to give help, either. But hey--I'm not complaining! (insert smiley face to express light-heartedness, in case you misinterpret this comment as well!) I will accept your answer as soon as the cooldown timer wears off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add line breaks whenever you wish. A simple approach is to just add a `'\n'` character after a certain number of numbers, say every 10. A more complex approach is to determine the width of the terminal and calculate how many numbers you can output per line.

You might also want to check out [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which allows you to set the width of each column in your table. Check out [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for details about the options available for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the library PrettyPrinter (a.k.a. pprint) you can set up indentation and depth levels and it handles all autonomously